Follow up question on the proper use of subset in complex survey designs
I read and tried to understand the various contributions on the proper subsetting in complex survey design, including:

Proper subsetting of survey data
When is subsetting survey data prior to analysis NOT a problem?
Why it is important to make survey design object (svydesign function in R with id, strata, weights, fpc) from raw data and after clean data in object?
https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2021/07/22/subsets-and-subpopulations-in-survey-inference/

I understand that when using subset() in svyby() the weights of the unselected observations are set to 0, am I correct?
I also understand that the point estimate does not differ for subsetting before constructing the survey design object or within svyby(), but the standard error and confidence interval do.
I think I understand or, at least imagine, the impact of both approaches for cluster sampling. If we drop clusters before constructing the survey design object, we assume that the dropped clusters did not exist and the remaining clusters represent the complete universe of possible clusters, while in fact the dropped clusters contain important information as well, i.e., they were empty. Am I right?
I have, however (or moreover) troubles with understanding the consequences for stratified sampling. What for information do we miss if we, for example, estimate the mean value for females, leaving males out (i.e., took a subset of female respondents before constructing the survey design object). While writing this, I wonder do we assume in stratified sampling that the variance in the male subpopulation provides information too about the variance in the female subpopulation in this case?
Thank you for your time; and please let me know if I need to provide more information.
